# Is it possible to access *loaded* children of a nodejs module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have 3 modules with dependencies like so:

A.js

```
var b = require('./B');
var c = require('./C');

console.log(module.children.length); // 2
```

B.js

```
var z = require('Z');

console.log(module.children.length); // 1
```

C.js

```
var z = require('Z');

console.log(module.children.length); // 0 ?!?!
```

`Z` doesn't appear in `module.children` inside `C` because it was already loaded by `B` before `C` was executed.

I can understand the `module.parent` of `Z` being `B` because that's the first place it was loaded, but surely `Z` can be a child of both `B` and `C`?

Anyway, my question: is it possible to see *all* children of a module, regardless of whether they've been loaded or not?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in the past and I manually deleted the cache, in your case for module C.

C.js

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve('./Z')];
var z = require('./Z'); // 1
```

I'm not sure if this is a feasible solution for you though.

Comment: Good idea.. but I can only change the top-level file (think: something with `var a = require('./A')`).. I'm trying to make a tool that displays dependencies by recursively looking through `module.children`

Comment: Good idea as well, sounds promising :). Well, how are you accessing the children module? Can you clean the cache before accessing it?

Comment: I'm making a single script file that takes a filename as a commandline arg, `require`s that file, then looks at its own `module.children` - the only item being the `module` that was loaded.  Then recurse through `module.children` dumping some info to the console.  Or, thats the aim..

Comment: I see, take a look at rewire. https://github.com/jhnns/rewire. Looking forward to hearing news about this script :)

Comment: something along the lines: rewire(module.children.id);

Comment: [this](https://github.com/alexmcmillan/listrequires) is what I've come up with.. I couldn't get anywhere with `rewire` but I looked into what the `require` object contained and managed to find a hook.  I'd love to know what you think